# Deploying a mobile app backend with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I need to some advice regarding how to deploy a high traffic mobile app back-end using kubernetes. This deployment should support HA at-least. We have plans to run a DR site as well, but scope of this question does not include a DR.

We currently use hardware load-balancers to route incoming traffic to different IP addresses attached to different boxes. Each such box runs a nginx instance as a reverse proxy which also act as the https terminator. After https termination, traffic is directed to an apache web-server. Each box has one apacher server receiving all traffic from nginx running in the same box.

We want to introduce kubernetes to this setup so that we can utilize boxes better. Our traffic patterns are highly fluctuating and we believe kubernetes can help us utilize boxes in a more efficient manner.

My current plan is as follows:

```
-- Keep the hardware load balancer to route incoming traffic to different boxes. (this may not be needed but getting rid of HLB could become very political).
-- Run a kubenetes cluster utilizing all available boxes
-- pack apache + our app as docker image and deploy this image on docker container which in tern is run inside pods in the kubenetes cluster
-- setup ingress to accept external traffic, do https termination and load balance to above pods. A simple round robin or random load balancing algo is fine as our back ends are stateless
```

Does this sound right? Are there any alternatives? In the above case, where does the ingress controller run?

Answer (score 0):

Your plan seems right. You can either pack apache with the code but it shall be better to keep it separate so that they can contact each other and any one of the version upgrades won't be dependent upon this one.

Also, the hardware load balancer will tickle the traffic on to the ingress which shall further bring it down to the k8s cluster and eventually on the pods.

Answer (score 0):

The ingress controller runs inside the cluster. I guess you're looking to run kuberentes on-premise with your existing hardware. To use the existing hardware loadbalancer outside of kubernetes you could run the nginx ingress controller as a daemonset so that there'd be one instance on each node and expose it via HostPort so that each is exposed on the same port. Or if there are [lots of nodes](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/875) then you'd want to just use a Deployment. Then you'd would want to use NodePort so that Kuberentes would send the traffic to a node where an ingress controller pod runs.

Another alternative would be to expose the nginx ingress controller through LoadBalancer - to do that you'd need to integrate your loadbalancer with kubernetes using something like https://hackernoon.com/metallb-a-load-balancer-for-bare-metal-kubernetes-clusters-f7320fde52f2

Alternatively, you wouldn't necessarily have to use ingress. You could just run [nginx in the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#creating-and-exploring-an-nginx-deployment) and expose it via NodePort.

It's not clear to me that you'd need apache http server in your container. I guess it depends how you are using it currently.

Comment: Our backed is written in php which needs apache. I will look in to your suggestions, Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit on deployment and nodeport. I am not very clear about how the flow of traffic happens in this case.

Comment: A couple of good links are http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ A more direct discussion is https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/872

Comment: A longer discussion is https://medium.com/@maniankara/kubernetes-tcp-load-balancer-service-on-premise-non-cloud-f85c9fd8f43c

Comment: @simonjohnson Nginx works with php app even better. Maybe there is some else reason?